# PHP: if condition then redirect1 else redirect2

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'm trying to make a really simple check here. I want to select from my db a record which represents a username and a password. Now the problem is where the `if` starts. Whether I'm putting in the form credentials that exist in the database or not I still don't get redirected. Besides using `mysqli_num_fields($result)`, I also tried using `mysqli_num_rows($result)` and it still doesn't work. This is starting to drive me nuts.

Also I tried a var_dump of $result and I got this:

```
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }
```

Which I'm not sure how to interpret.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","XXXXX","test");
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT uid FROM test.login WHERE uid = '$uid' AND pass = '$pass'");
if(mysqli_num_fields($result) == 0) { header('Location: index.html')} else { header('form.html')}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks in advance. This is probably a rather stupid question and I apologize for that, but understand I'm rather new in all LAMP.

Comment: `mysqli_query` and `mysql_num_fields`? Aren't you messing here?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I actually tried with mysqli_num_fields aswell and I got the same result.

Comment: PHP manual says that there's no `mysqli_num_fields` function.

Comment: Are you quite certain that '$_POST` contains what you expect it to?  If so, did you verify your SQL statement is correct?

Comment: I have also used mysqli_num_rows and same thing. but yeah, bluefish(code editor, maybe not the best) is autocompleting that for me, so basically it's telling me there is such a method.

Comment: Did an _echo "" . $pass . " " . $uid ;_ and got what i was expecting

Comment: And what shows `var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($result))`?

Comment: try to print the query and see what query is being posted to mysql...if query is right then copy and paste it into sql tab of phpmyadmin and see what results it gives...if possible post them here

Comment: well apparently the output of var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($result)) is `int(0)`  
about the query i get no results with SELECT uid FROM test.login WHERE uid = 'Username' AND pass = 'Password'
I'm using mysql workbench btw

Comment: It's weird that you print the variables and get what you expected. Have you checked the connection? If you do a regular query to your db, does it return anything? 
Example, if you set `$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM test.login");` do you get any results? (does the line you wish to query show up on this result?)

Comment: well `var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($result));` with `$sql = "SELECT * FROM test.login ";` is returning `int(1)` and connection is good i think. since it's returning int(1) and there is just one record in the DB

Comment: As a sanity check, I would suggest you print all the lines that "SELECT * FROM test.login" returns. Just to make sure the line you are looking for is actually returned. Other things I can think of: is your `$pass` variable properly SHA1'ed or properly SALTed (if it's the case)? (maybe the password is right but you forgot to do the hashing part before comparing to the database)... and oh, that reminds me of something: what is the type of the column `pass` on your database? maybe your SHA1 value is getting truncated when inserted into the db, and then the `=` wouldnt work on the querying.

Comment: still, i think the problem is that `if` not doing quite anything since it's not redirecting me anywhere. i just remain on the `login.php` page. though the condition is false since `int(1)` is not equals to `0` it won't redirect me to the `form.html`

about the pass column, that's varchar(30). I will try to print all the rows, tho i'm not sure how. will look for some code really fast and i'll be back

Comment: did this

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['uid'] . " " . $row['pass'];
  echo "<br>";
  }`

and got my only record i have in my DB which is what i was supposed to get i believe.

Comment: if you think that's the problem, try doing the opposite (check if it's not 0):
`if(mysqli_num_fields($result) <> 0) {header('form.html') } else { header('Location: index.html')}`

Comment: tried that, didn't work either. at first i thought it was something about the parenthesis messing up, but apparently it's not, and i'm pretty much lost

Comment: Do you have any HTML or echo code before the if condition? because PHP does not allow any calls to `header` after any echo or html

Comment: You should use `mysqli_num_rows`, not `mysqli_num_fields`. Notice when you output `var_dump($result)`, the field count is 1 but the row count is 0. Rows is what you're after: 0 rows, 0 results. The number of fields is obvious in this case because your `SELECT` statement has 1 field (uid).

Comment: well that makes perfect sense actually. one more problem tho, if i do a select * i get 1 row, but the result of `var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($result))` is `int(1)` and not `1`. what can I do about this? cuz basically it's returning me a string i believe, stating that `int(1)` and not an integer like `1`

Comment: No, that's just how [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) works, it shows a type and a value.

Comment: If `SELECT * FROM <table>` returns 1 row and your full query doesn't, try removing the password portion of your `WHERE` clause, and see if it returns the row or not. Then try leaving it in but removing the uid part. See if returns a row for either of these cases.

Comment: phew, done... just had to finish up things by setting the full query... thanks a lot man ! TIL: var_dump returns a type and a value... that will be useful. thanks again! one last question! Where's the thanks button? :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the right header. A bit of formatting reveals the difference between if- and else-branch:

```
if(mysqli_num_fields($result) == 0) { 
    header('Location: index.html')
} else { 
    header('form.html')
}
```

You should use

```
if(mysqli_num_fields($result) == 0) { 
    header('Location: index.html');
} else { 
    header('Location: form.html');
}
```

instead.

As @u_mulder remarked, PHP-Docu mentions no such function/method as mysqli_num_fields().
Your code is prone to SQL-Injection, you should properly escape the user input with [mysqli_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). Even better: use prepared statements.
A successful login should depend of just one matching row in your result.

A sidenote: it's a very bad idea to store cleartext passwords.

Comment: well this worked half way. i mean it's always taking me to `index.html `with `mysqli_num_fields($result) <> 0` as if condition

Comment: Try this answer except using the appropriate function to examine `$result`: `mysqli_num_rows`.

Comment: Changed to ..._rows but i always get redirected to index.html. Code looks like this right now:
`<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","xxxxx","test");
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test.login "; //WHERE uid = '$uid' AND pass = '$pass'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

  
//var_dump($result);

//var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($result));

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) <> 0) { header('Location: index.html'); } else { header('Location: form.html');}


mysqli_close($con);
?>`